# Pythonic way using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have this code that I know can be much more efficient....

```
return_list = []
for attribute in attributes:
    if attribute['internalname'] in attributenames:
        attr = Attribute();
        attr.name = attribute['internalname']
        attr.value = attribute['value']
        return_list.append(attr);

return return_list
```

I could have easily done list comprehension but since there is an object creation `attr=Attributes()`, I don't know how would I handle that?

Comment: It won't be more efficient, only less verbose.

Comment: @f.rodrigues Less verbose often is also less readable; often a generator is better than a long list comprehension, specially if you don't need a real list.

Comment: Indeed. This for loop is very clear, while the answer made it worse in readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `Attribute()` take the name and value as arguments:

```
return [Attribute(attr['internalname'], attr['value'])
        for attr in attributes if attr['internalname'] in attributenames]
```

You could make it accept keyword arguments instead if you need to support various attributes instead:

```
return [Attribute(name=attr['internalname'], value=attr['value'])
        for attr in attributes if attr['internalname'] in attributenames]
```

If neither is an option, make a function to create the `Attribute` object with a `name` and `value` attribute:

```
def create_attribute(name, value):
    attr = Attribute()
    attr.name = name
    attr.value = value
    return attr

return [create_attribute(attr['internalname'], attr['value'])
        for attr in attributes if attr['internalname'] in attributenames]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there an `__init__` method for `Attribute` that takes named parameters? If so, you could do something like

```
return_list = [Attribute(name=attribute['internalname'], value=attribute['value']) for attribute in attributes if attribute['internalname'] in attributenames]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is meant as a comment, posting as an answer because the comment system is not suited for posting code samples. There are two good answers using list comprehensions and I want to complement talking about generators and generator expressions.

While a list comprehension is shorter than your function, it may also be less readable. An alternative is using generators:

```
def make_attributes(attributes, attributenames):
    for attribute in attributes:
        if attribute['internalname'] in attributenames:
            attr = Attribute();
            attr.name = attribute['internalname']
            attr.value = attribute['value']
            yield attr
```

There is also generator expressions (use these in place of list comprehensions where you don't really need a real list, for example, when you are just iterating over the result):

```
# borrowing create_attribute from Martijn Pieters
return (
    create_attribute(attr['internalname'], attr['value'])
    for attr in attributes 
    if attr['internalname'] in attributenames
)
```